# Enhancement Request: Indicate on the Tag listings when a tag is a synonym of another

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I wanted to define some tags today (so many are left undefined when created) and chose to set the filter to "popular" and jump the the [last page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags?page=22&tab=popular).

As it turns out, every single tag on the last page is a synonym of another tag and therefore cannot be edited. *But you can't know that without clicking on each and every tag to see that it redirects to another tag.* Even rolling the mouse over the tag name doesn't clearly reveal the tag to be a synonym — but it could confuse the user who compares the rollover popup's >0 questions with the original tag's 0 questions. A hint, but not a very good one, and still an inconvenient way to try and upgrade tags.

It would be tremendously helpful if synonyms were identified, especially in a way that also identified the parent.  Something like this:

[image]

Comment: While you can hope for this FR to get implemented, in the mean time you can use a SEDE query to get the info you need: https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/1825931

Comment: @rene Hope is all I have, SE's track record for implementing even simple common-sense enhancements appears poor. Thanks for the link and the recommendation.